# Java local variable vs global field - Performance

Tags: java, spring, web-services, class, global-variables

I have a private method which takes date in as String type and returns `XMLGregorianCalendar` object with specific format. This method is being invoked from various other methods within the same class.
The format defined as `SimpleDateFormat` which is same for every invocation. Below are the 2 versions of the method.

**Version 1:**

```
private XMLGregorianCalendar getXmlGregorianCalendar(final String strDt) throws ParseException, DatatypeConfigurationException{
        Date date = null;
        // local variable dtFormat
        DateFormat dtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss");
        if (strDt != null) {
            date = dtFormat.parse(strDt);
            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            cal.setTime(date);
            XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal);
            return xmlCal;
       }else {
           return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new GregorianCalendar());
       }
    }
```

**Version 2:**

```
// declare date format once, global variable
private DateFormat dtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss");

// getter setter for dtFormat

private XMLGregorianCalendar getXmlGregorianCalendar(final String strDt) throws ParseException, DatatypeConfigurationException{
        Date date = null;
        if (strDt != null) {
            date = this.dtFormat.parse(strDt); // of course, getDtFormat() can be used
            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            cal.setTime(date);
            XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal);
            return xmlCal;
       }else {
           return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new GregorianCalendar());
       }
    }
```

Version 1 vs Version 2. Which has better performance?

**Note:** The enclosed class is annotated as `@Component` and involved in creating response for my web service.

Comment: If it is a multithreaded environment, you might want to look at some other thread-safe formatter. SimpleDateFormat will be messed up when two threads access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe, so that would be something to consider. Performance has little to do with this question, unless you really don't have any other performance hotspots (which would be surprising).

You can however use a `ThreadLocal` `SimpleDateFormat`, but remember that `ThreadLocals` have their own issues, and it probably doesn't really matter.

Comment: Well they're quite annoying at leaking resources.

Comment: Leave about SimpleDateFormat, if it is a different class (which is thread-safe), then which has better performance, V1 or V2?

Comment: @Sridhar It really doesn't matter. You're micro-optimizing, which is just not smart. If you however think that this is very important, then you'll surely want to measure the performance of both and realize that you just wasted time on something completely unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

If that `SimpleDateFormat` is a constant, you can make it `static final` and it would improve your performance just a little bit. But you should be aware of the concept of `static` fields in classes. `static` fields **are allocated once in memory for all instances** of your @Component class. So if this cannot creating a bug in your code, it's better to define it as a constant using `static final` keywords.